# SharePoint Office 365 - Starting the ID field at 50,000 which incrementally grows

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to premise that I am not a coder, and have limited SharePoint experience. Nonetheless, I have a task at work to create a new tool for a group at work. This tool will allow them to track things through its life-cycle. The old tool will stop being used once they hit the 49,999th record. At that point we will transition to SharePoint. The prior numbers will live with those records and we will be unable to start back at the number 1.

My goal is to have an ID field for each record that incrementally grows starting from the number 50,000.

I tried creating a new calculated formula field that does 50,000 plus the ID but it does not work effectively. There tends to be a lag. The lag can be anywhere from 5 minutes to a day or two. In turn, I need an alternative option.

With a friends coaching, I am messing with SharePoint designer to automatically create a record once one is deleted and delete one every time one is created. However, this times out occasionally. Even more so, it is extremely slow. It will take me a week or so to get to 50,000. Does anyone have any experience or expertise to assist me? It is very appreciated.

Comment: Please leave out the noise, and ask a specific question please.

Comment: In office 365 SharePoint 2013, how do I enable a field within a list that starts at 50,000 and incrementally grows without a lag?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to create another field and used that in all my views. Update it through a SharePoint Designer workflow on create - set the field to ID+50000, for example, or whatever you need. Maybe give it a bit of a buffer and set it to ID+51000. By the time the workflow is running the ID has been created and you can use it in a workflow.

If you are going to be moving your old records to the list, you can change the workflow to only update the new field if it's blank. That way you can save the original ids.